# 'IF' condition misbehaving

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here is a code that determines whether an input is PRIME number or not.

```py
def is_prime(x):
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
        if x < 2 or x % n == 0: 
            return False
    else: 
        return True
```

But the `if` condition inside the `for` loop doesn't work as expected. If `x < 2`, it should return false. So `is_prime(1)` should return false as 1 is less than 2. But the program returns True instead, which is not expected. On the other hand, if you put that `if` just outside the for loop like this, IT WORKS:

```py
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2: return False
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
        if x % n == 0: 
            return False
    else: return True
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe loop up what `or` does.

Comment: your `else` is outside the `for`, replace that with just `return true`

Comment: If anything that's _misbehaving_ here, it is the logic.

Comment: Hint: check the value of `range(2, 2-1)` a debugging print statement just inside the `for` would have showed you the loop never runs.

Comment: For the benefit if those less familiar with Python (I just had to look it up), it has the peculiar feature of having [loop `else` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), which are meant to be used with `break` (which will *skip* `else` part, normal loop termination will evaluate it).

Comment: @xF The `else` is put outside of the `for` loop for a purpose, it's not a mistake. the `else` runs just after normal termination of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over here,

```
for n in range(2, x - 1):
```

the for loop never runs if x == 1, then, you are essentially saying:

```
for n in range(2, 0):
```

which can't happen, so it just returns True from the `else` statement.

Your second function works because, as you said, the if statement is outside of the `for` loop

Comment: But wait, I put the `if x < 2` condition before the `range(2, x-1)`, doesn't it mean that the python interpreter will give the first part high priority and if that condition doesn't match, it would ignore the second logic after `or` ?

Comment: @AhmedSadman Do you mean like this: http://ideone.com/e.js/Xw3KnJ?    AFAIK If you say: `if x < 2 or x % n == 0: for n in range(2, x-1)` then if `x` is smaller than 2, then the `x % n == 0` will never run. But if x is bigger than 2, then the `x % n == 0` will run .

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 9:
        return x in {2, 3, 5, 7}
    elif not (x % 2):
        # even
        return False
    else:
        upto = int(x ** 0.5)  # test to sqrt(x)
        # test divisibility by odd numbers
        return all(x % div for div in range(3, upto+1, 2))
```